# Where do I post a question on how to use apps?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on using the app 'TightVNC'. I see lots of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I understand this is now reserved for programming only questions. What is the best Stack Exchange site to post questions about how to use apps?

Comment: Superuser.com.  Make sure your question is specific, and demonstrates prior effort at researching and solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 5):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is the site for you, since "computer software" is [explicitly on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Furthermore, for your particular case, they have handled [over 100 questions about TightVNC already](https://superuser.com/search?q=tightvnc+is%3Aquestion).

However, note that questions specifically related to using *Web* applications belong on [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), since "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" are expressly *off*-topic on Super User

Answer (score 4):

That would seem to be on-topic for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about
>
> - computer software
>
> ...